# How deserialize based on information available in the parent class

Tags: java, json, generics, enums, jackson

I am using Jackson to deserialize a number of different implementations of the `Product` interface. These product implementations have different fields, but all have an `InsuredAmount` field. This `InsuredAmount` class has a value field and an `IAType` field. The `IAType` is a marker interface with different enums as implementations.

Now here's the problem: The enum implementations of the `IAType` interface correspond to a certain implementation of the `Product` interface. How can I make a generic implementation and tell Jackson to find the correct implementation of thee IAType? Should I use a generic parameter on the Product and the IAType interface identifying the product implementation? Should I use a `Productable` functional interface on the classes identifying the product implementation? How can I tell Jackson to use that implementation?

I hope the code below clarifies the problem, I chose to implement a `Productable` interface here, but a bettere structure to handle this problem would also be welcome.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"type", "someInfo"})
public class InsuredAmount implements Productable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private IAType type;

    private String someInfo;

    public InsuredAmount() {
    }

    public InsuredAmount(IAType typeA, String someInfo) {
        this.type = typeA;
        this.someInfo = someInfo;
    }


    /* This should be on the product level, but if I can solve this problem,
    the next level will just be more of the same.
    */
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Product getProduct() {
        return Product.PROD_A;
    }

    // Getters, setters, equals, etc. omitted.
}
```

--

```
public interface Productable {

    public Product getProduct();

}
```

--

```
public enum Product {

    PROD_A, PROD_B;

}
```

--

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = IATypeDeserializer.class)
public interface IAType extends Productable {

}
```

--

```
public enum IATypeA implements IAType {

    FOO, BAR;

    @Override
    public Product getProduct() {
        return Product.PROD_A;
    }

}
```

--

```
public class IATypeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<IAType> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public IATypeDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public IATypeDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public IAType deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        /* How to find out that the class calling the deserialization is InsuredAmountA, which
        has getProduct() method that returns PROD_A, and matches the IATypeA that also returns
        PROD_A, so I know to deserialize IATypeA, instead of other implementations of the IAType
        interface?
        */
        return IATypeA.valueOf(node.asText());
    }

}
```

--

```
public class InsuredAmountTest {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void test01() throws IOException {
        InsuredAmount iaA = new InsuredAmount(IATypeA.FOO, "test it");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(iaA);
        assertThat(json, is("{\"type\":\"FOO\",\"someInfo\":\"test it\"}"));
        InsuredAmount iaA2 = mapper.readValue(json, InsuredAmount.class);
        IAType type = iaA2.getType();
        assertThat(type, is(IATypeA.FOO));
        assertThat(type.getProduct(), is(Product.PROD_A));
        assertThat(iaA, is(iaA2));
    }

    @Test
    public void test02() throws IOException {
        InsuredAmount iaA = new InsuredAmount(IATypeA.BAR, "test it");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(iaA);
        assertThat(json, is("{\"type\":\"BAR\",\"someInfo\":\"test it\"}"));
        InsuredAmount iaA2 = mapper.readValue(json, InsuredAmount.class);
        assertThat(iaA, is(iaA2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with using `JsonCreator` annotation on a special constructor.

```
    @JsonCreator
    public InsuredAmountA(
            @JsonProperty("type") String type,
            @JsonProperty("someInfo") String someInfo) throws IOException {
        switch (getProduct()) {
            case PROD_A:
                try {
                    this.type = IATypeA.valueOf(type);
                    break;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    // Throw IOException in the default.
                }
//            case PROD_B:
//                this.type = (IATypeB) typeA;
//                break;
            default:
                throw new IOException(String.format("Cannot parse value %s as type.", type));
        }
        this.someInfo = someInfo;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Jackson handles the serialization of enums with minimal fuss, so all you need to do is annotate the `IAType` field with `@JsonTypeInfo`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS)
private IAType type;
```

Then a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new InsuredAmount(IATypeA.FOO, "info"));
    System.out.println(json);
    InsuredAmount ia = mapper.readValue(json, InsuredAmount.class);
    System.out.println("Type is: " + ia.getType());
}
```

results in the output:

```
{"type":[".IATypeA","FOO"],"someInfo":"info"}
Type is: FOO
```

To get a more compact representation you will have to use custom serialization. Assuming that there are no overlaps in your enum namespace, you can serialize the type field as the enum name.

The deserializer will need to know which types are available for construction, either by class path discovery or, as in the following example, simply hard-coding the references:

```
public class IATest {

    public static class IATypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<IAType> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(IAType value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeString(((Enum) value).name());
        }
    }

    public static class IATypeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<IAType> {
        @Override
        public IAType deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            String value = p.readValueAs(String.class);
            try {
                return IATypeA.valueOf(value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // fall through
            }
            try {
                return IATypeB.valueOf(value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // fall through
            }
            throw new JsonMappingException(p, "Unknown type '" + value + "'");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Register a module to handle serialization of IAType implementations
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(IAType.class, new IATypeSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(IAType.class, new IATypeDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        // Test
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new InsuredAmount(IATypeA.FOO, "info"));
        System.out.println(json);
        InsuredAmount ia = mapper.readValue(json, InsuredAmount.class);
        System.out.println("Type is: " + ia.getType());
    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
{"type":"FOO","someInfo":"info"}
Type is: FOO
```

Comment: The point is that it that the class that I am using is InsuredAmountA of which the IAType is a field. So I think the ".IATypeA" addition to the serialized class is not necessary in my case. But how can I tell that to Jackson?

Comment: So your goal is a clean json representation? Could you add some acceptable examples to your question?

Comment: Examples are in the provided testcases: `assertThat(json, is("{\"type\":\"FOO\",\"someInfo\":\"test it\"}"))`. Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: Just wanting to understand if there is some wriggle room for including type info, for example `"type": {"name":"FOO", product:"PROD_A"}`, or if you require the mapping to be performed only with the IAType implementation enum name.

Comment: Sorry, that would lead to a lot of duplicate information in the serialized objects. There is a Product object above the InsuredAmount, that has a collection of InsuredAmounts.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an option that uses custom serialization.

Comment: I understand what you did here. There are enum values that are in multiple IAType implementations. So this solution would possibly return the wrong IAType implementation.

Comment: Is there a one-to-one mapping between `Products` and the `IAType`? You might be able to qualify the enum with the product name. If that's not the case, I can't see a way that you can perform the mapping without including some type information in the serialized object.

Comment: Found a solution after a good night of sleep. Simpler than expected, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into direction of polymorphic deserialisation:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

unsing custom type resolver

Comment: Yeah, I already looked into that. Couldn't figure out how to use that in my case.

Comment: @JsonTypeResolver seems to be the annotation you need,   I would look into sources ( jackson is a good piece of code and easy to understand )  and harass Tatu Saloranta whi is the author -  he is usually responsible and lives somewhere in west coast